# Can I run scriptcs with useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy?

Tags: .net-4.0, scriptcs

I have a DLL (Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser) which I need to reference in a scriptcs file.

The following DLL can only be referenced if **useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy** is included in the app.config file.

For example, this console application:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var batchParser = new ManagedBatchParser.Parser();
        }
    }
}
```

will only compile if I include **useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy** in the app.config like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">    
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/></startup>
</configuration>
```

But doing the same in a CSX file:

```
#r "Microsoft.Sqlserver.BatchParser"

var batchParser = new ManagedBatchParser.Parser();
```

will fail because I don't know how to specify this attribute. I get the infamous error as soon as I try to run the scriptcs file:

> Additional information: Mixed mode assembly is built against version
>   'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime
>   without additional configuration information.

So my main question is, how can I tell scriptcs to start compiling the CSX file with the useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy attribute ?

Comment: You simply need a scriptcs.exe.config with the same content.

Comment: Great! it worked. Do you want post an answer, and I will accept it ? or I  can answer myself.

Comment: This question is answered. Please see the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37878353/scriptcs-mixed-mode-assembly-error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app.config file will be renamed to *program*.exe.config. In order to do this with ScriptCS you just need a file named scriptcs.exe.config that has the **useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy** startup node in it.